# How to test for Windows 7 platform?

Tags: java, windows-7, platform

I have a Java app which needs to run differently when on Windows 7.

How would you check which Windows version is present? Is it enough to check for OS version 6.1?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm also wondering what the version number will look like after the next service pack - 6.1.1 or what? If so, it's not a simple double any more...

Comment: If you need to check for the Windows version, you're probably attacking your problem from the wrong angle. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @So/ren - it's just that the pc dept want to change the default data storage path for new (Win7) rollouts. I will have to use a separate path. I guess I could request an environment variable but it's too late now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the same problem checking also for `os.name`, in a null-safe way:

```
public boolean runningOnWindows7() {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
    return "Windows 7".equals(osName) && "6.1".equals(osVersion);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OS Version Numbers are rather distinct.

For example, XP is denoted with the number 5.1 and Windows 7 denoted by 6.1

The build numbers determine the updates, and service packs.

It should be rather reliable checking OS version number. but keep in mind that Java is allowed to run on Linux and Mac if Java is installed on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("os.name") 
System.getProperty("os.version")
```

Windows 7 = version 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Fix to **dfa**'s answer:

```
public boolean runningOnWindows7() {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
    return "Windows 7".equals(osName) || "6.1".equals(osVersion);
}
```

|| instead of &&